# I have flickering dash and battery lights

Tags: mazda, dash, tribute

I have a 2003 Mazda Tribute v6.

The dash lights when on flicker and I have been told so do the headlights,since I got this in Nov. had a trip to FL and back and no problems except the flickering. I had the checked battery and alternator checked and they were fine. Yesterday the battery light began to flick on and off. As I had work done the day before I took it back to the shop. They checked the alternator and battery and said they were working as they should then scanned it and showed no problem but still the dash and now battery still flicker?

Comment: Have the shop remove clean the battery terminals and check connection at battery negative cable at its ground point on the engine,

Comment: This sounds like a grounding issue, but you'd have to go through all of your grounds, both to body and to engine to ensure they are good.

Comment: It could also be a defective headlight switch.